# Answering Yes/No shell prompt on notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm running a [shell execute](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-sx) command in a notebook (Google Collaboratory), and such command prompts me to give a yes/no answer. How can I respond to this prompt shell message within the notebook?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**: Colab now supports input prompts, so you should see these immediately, e.g.,

[image]

**Old answer:** A typical pattern is to run the command without prompts, if it has such an option. For example, for installation using `apt`, provide the option `-y`.

If no such option exists, you can do something like piping yes to the program like so: `yes | programThatHasConfirmationPrompts`.

Comment: This solved my issue. However, I think what can I do if I have multiple prompts on a single execution (and I'm not able to pass parameters upfront).

Answer (score 2):

Colab input prompts did not pop out for my command but the pipelining worked, for example:

```
!yes | sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://someURL...)"
```