# How to key in "Yes" or "No" in Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431895/answering-yes-no-shell-prompt-on-notebook) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798181/jupyter-notebook-is-there-a-way-to-answer-y-to-or-ignore-all-y-n-prompts). But it doesn't solve my problem. Please don't mark it as duplicate

I am trying to run the below piece of code in `Jupyter Notebook` with `R kernel`.

```
model_predictors <- buildModel(flag, fv_full_data, outcomeName, folder)
```

I get an error message like below

```
Model about to be built   # this is log message and not error

1 package is needed for this model and is not installed. (randomForest). Would you like to try to install it now?    # here I see that it asks for a question but without my input it selects `No`
Error: Required package is missing
Traceback:

1. buildModel(flag, fv_full_data, outcomeName, folder)
2. train(x = trainDF[, predictorsNames], y = factor(trainLabels), 
 .     method = "rf", metric = "Fscore", trControl = objControl, 
 .     tuneGrid = rf_grid, preProcess = c("center", "scale"))
3. train.default(x = trainDF[, predictorsNames], y = factor(trainLabels), 
 .     method = "rf", metric = "Fscore", trControl = objControl, 
 .     tuneGrid = rf_grid, preProcess = c("center", "scale"))
4. checkInstall(models$library)
5. stop("Required package is missing", call. = FALSE)
```

How can I avoid this error and prevent jupyter selecting `No` as default for dynamic prompts?

Comment: I think you shouldn't rely on automatic prompts to install the packages you need. Run `install.packages("randomForest")` once, and this problem should go away.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But may I know/learn from you to know that is there any way to key in `yes` or `no` in `jupyter notebook` during runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you actually never reach the part of code that handles input. These inputs only occur for interactive sessions - which Jupyter is not. You can check with

```
interactive()
#> FALSE

menu(c("yes", "no"))
#> Error in menu(c("yes", "no")): menu() cannot be used non-interactively
#> Traceback:
#> 
#> 1. menu(c("yes", "no"))
#> 2. stop("menu() cannot be used non-interactively")
```

`caret::checkInstall` prints out the message "Would you like to try to install x now?", but it will only accept input for interactive sessions.

Here is the code for `caret::checkInstall` with my comments.

```
function (pkg) 
{
    good <- rep(TRUE, length(pkg))
    for (i in seq(along = pkg)) {
        tested <- try(find.package(pkg[i]), silent = TRUE)
        if (inherits(tested, "try-error")) 
            good[i] <- FALSE
    }
    if (any(!good)) {
        pkList <- paste(pkg[!good], collapse = ", ")
        msg <- paste(sum(!good), ifelse(sum(!good) > 1, " packages are", 
            " package is"), " needed for this model and", 
            ifelse(sum(!good) > 1, " are", " is"), 
            " not installed. (", pkList, "). Would you like to try to install", 
            ifelse(sum(!good) > 1, " them", " it"), 
            " now?", sep = "")
        cat(msg) # Print the message
        if (interactive()) { # In Jupyter, `interactive()` is `FALSE`.
            bioc <- c("affy", "logicFS", "gpls", 
                "vbmp")
            installChoice <- menu(c("yes", "no")) # This is where it gets input
            if (installChoice == 1) {
                hasBioc <- any(pkg[!good] %in% bioc)
                if (!hasBioc) {
                  install.packages(pkg[!good])
                }
                else {
                  inst <- pkg[!good]
                  instC <- inst[!(inst %in% bioc)]
                  instB <- inst[inst %in% bioc]
                  if (length(instC) > 0) 
                    install.packages(instC)
                  biocLite <- NULL
                  source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
                  biocLite(instB)
                }
            }
            else stop("Required package is missing", call. = FALSE)
        }
        else stop("Required package is missing", call. = FALSE) # Because `interactive()` is `FALSE`, this `stop` is called
    }
}
```

For your situation, `install.packages("randomForest")` is the best option.

If you were in `RStudio`, you could use the `rstudioapi` like this

```
f <- function() {
  rstudioapi::sendToConsole("1")
  menu(c("yes", "no"))
}
f()
#> 1: yes
#> 2: no
#> 
#> Selection: 1
#> [1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

*Mind that in modern Jupyter Notebooks, you better take Magic commands (starting with `%` instead of `!` in front of a command), see the comments.*

---

I did not test with the R kernel, but this might still help someone.

##### Example: Python package manager conda

You can add `-y` to the install command so that a "yes" is the default for any `yes/no` prompt.

This does not work:

```bash
!conda install matplotlib
```

Output:

```bash
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-panel-2023.05-py310

  added / updated specs:
    - matplotlib


The following packages will be UPDATED:

  certifi                         2023.7.22-py311h06a4308_0 --> 2023.11.17-py311h06a4308_0 
  openssl                                 3.0.10-h7f8727e_2 --> 3.0.12-h7f8727e_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Which I cannot enter since there is no interactive user prompt in Jupyter Notebook.

On the other hand,

```bash
!conda install matplotlib -y
```

does not ask for *yes/no* anymore. You tell that you have already tried this and that it does not work for the R Kernel, but at least for python installers, it should be tried.

##### Example: apt-get install

The question lists the link that shows:

```bash
apt-get -y install [packagename]`
```

But if you check [Automatically answer 'Yes' when using apt-get install](https://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install) on Super User and then scroll through other answers there, you will find other tricks like:

```bash
!DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
!apt-get --yes --force-yes install $something
```

---

*PS: Since these tricks did not work for the R Kernel, this answer does not help answering the question as a whole, but at least, it may be an answer to its title. It might be a little step beyond the already given link.*

Comment: Please, when offering advice it is best your suggestions use current best practices and not versions that may cause problems inadvertently. Use of an exclamation point with install commands doesn't insure it installs to the correct environment, and so the magic variations of the install commands were added in 2019 to insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that is backing the active .ipynb in which you run the installation, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). ...

Comment: <continued> Specifically, your post should suggest `%conda install matplotlib -y` for Python-based kernels. (`%pip install <package name>` will also work for pyodide-based kernels.)  More at top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) about why the exclamation point for installations is not best and can lead to issues.

Comment: And I tested that with an R kernel running in Jupyter. Either symbol in front of `conda install` throws an error.

Comment: @Wayne Thanks for making this clearer. Then, please advise, shall I delete the answer? Or would it be good to take up your thoughts and edit the answer to "warn" other users? By the way, if you run this in Anaconda's cloud for Jupyter, it should always install anything to the chosen environment. I guess. Anything else would be astonishing since you do not have access to other environments in that isolated cloud session.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily advise deleting it because you are addressing the title part. Your call. Sorry, I didn't catch it was in the cloud but it holds for all modern Jupyter so it is better advice. (Google Colab though isn't modern Jupyter as the present fork it is based on frustratingly predates the addition of the magic install commands.) Either way you decide on deletion or leaving, the use of the magic command is good advice even if it is just for you for Jupyter in more places going forward.

Comment: Leaving it since the readers will also learn about the magic commands you speak about.